# badge on iphone homescreen

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, homescreen

Is it possible to show a alphabet/special character instead of number on the app icon on home screen ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can only display positive numbers.

Comment: how about the badges inside the app' uitabaritem ? i tried to change that to "*" and it worked. I tried it using IB. Is there any standard for this ?[edited]

Comment: @thndrkiss: the Apple docs say `UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber` is an `NSInteger` while `UITabBarItem.badgeValue` is an `NSString`. There's no real standard for this, but most apps use them both for numbers.

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention any restrictions and the badgeValue property is an NSString* so I assume it's ok.